# Would this be an example of a regular function?

Tags: functions, algebraic-geometry

In my class, we define regular functions as

> $f: \mathbb{A}^m \to \mathbb{A}^n$ is call regular iff $f = (f_1,...,f_n), f_i: \mathbb{A}^m \to \mathbb{A}^1$ is a polynomial, i.e. $f_i \in K[x_1,...,x_m]$

So I was trying to understand it and make a simple example:

$f: \mathbb{A}^3 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ is call regular iff $f = (f_1,f_2), f_i: \mathbb{A}^3 \to \mathbb{A}^1$ is a polynomial, i.e. $f_i \in K[x,y,z].$
$f_1(x,y,z) = x+1$ and $f_2(x,y,z) = y+10$

Would you say this is a good example that fits the definition? If not, can you tell me what is wrong and how to correct it?

Comment: Yes, that is an example. I think the definition is pretty clear. You could also take $f_1(x,y,z)=x^2y-2z^5+12$ for instance.

Comment: @CaptainLama okay, thank you! Also, I am unsure if I have to create a separate question for this, but do you know what would be V(J)  in this case?